# How do I highlight a whole row in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the orange part across the whole screen instead of just on the text? So when someone hovers over it, the orange color comes up on the selected menu item

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1wCL.png)

Here is my code

```css
    * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    }

    html {
 background: #76787a;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
    }

    .container {
 text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
    }

    a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #c67b3d;
    }

    a:hover {
 background-color: green;
    }

    .menu li a {
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 160px;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="container">
    <nav class="menu">
   <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
     </div>
```

Comment: set the width of the a tag to 100%

Comment: I put your code in a snippet, but you should know that you forgot the opening and closing list tags

Comment: You'll want to put the `background-color` on the `<li>` tags, and make them `width: 100%` as well. That will stretch the orange background to 100% of the width.

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing nav tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

Amend your css file:
Put:

```
background-color: #c67b3d; max-width: 100%;
```

in .container

Answer (score 1):

Make `.menu li a`  `display: block`.

Not sure if you want `margin-bottom: 10px;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background: #76787a;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #c67b3d;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display: block` to the `a` element. You can even get rid of `<li>` elements and the `<nav>` element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#">WORK</a>
  <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfvf10g5/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15322922)

Comment: @MohammadFaisal you are correct. I edited my comment. Not sure why that doesn't work :/ perhaps because it's missing the `<ul></ul>` and a closing `</nav>`??

Answer (score 0):

```css
    * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    }

    html {
 background: #76787a;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
    }

    .container {
 text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #c67b3d;
    max-width: 100%;
    }

    a {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #c67b3d;
    }

    a:hover {
 background-color: green;
    }

    .menu li a {
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 160px;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="container">
    <nav class="menu">
   <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

colour effect need to be apply on `.menu li` instead of `.menu li a`.

snippet of this code is 
[here.](http://codepen.io/h-a-r-d-i-k/pen/gmOQxN)